# Can anyone explain the negative values and the black lines on the x axis?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

[image]

Hello guys! I'm a student that just started learning about A.I. and machine learning through an online bootcamp. One of the assignments got me stuck because I can't find any resources to explain to me what are the negative values and black lines on the x axis of this picture about. Can anyone explain to me more about this and if this figure is correct or not? Thank you in advance!

[edit] The assignment I'm doing for this downloaded the data and plotted a graph without any manual intervention. Therefore, I'm unable to view the data or provide additional info. The question is just to see if I understand if the graph is incorrect and why.

Comment: The question is more generic. Why can't you look at your own data itself? Please mention any specific issue

Comment: I cannot see your data, which would be helpful to post.  Is it possible that your x-axis labels are very numerous and overprinting one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forgot to convert string to float. Like it should be

```
number = float(string)
```

when you read your input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Negative values - It seems your data has garbage values / outliers OR, some dummy value to represent missing data (such as -100, instead of Nan). I would recommend remove them or better, replace them with something else. You can try replacing them with 0 or imputing them with average values of the value before and after them, to keep the trend of the graph smooth.
2. Black lines on X axis - There are a large number of axis labels in X axis and they are overlapping to create a messy picture. You can either Bin the X axis to create buckets OR you can increase the figure length with figsize() function.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! The assignment I'm doing for this downloaded the data and plotted a graph without any manual intervention. Without any hints or explanation they asked me to figure out what's wrong with the figure. I'm able to better understand the figure now, thank you so much!

Comment: Cheers. Glad to be of help

Comment: @littleal4 makes me wonder about the quality of your bootcamp